# Book about smart girl whose mother drowned in the ocean

Tags: identification-request

This was a book I read in primary school (first read to me when I was 8 yrs old in 2014 in Australia) and the only thing I remember about the cover was that it was pink. The copy that my school had was kind of beat up so I couldn't tell how old it was. It was a paperback book and was about same the thickness of the book 'Soon', I think. The book was in English and I don't remember if it was a stand-alone book. I think that the book was targeted to teens or preteens and was maybe set between the 2010s to the 1990s at the latest.

The story is about a girl who is smart and is moved up a grade but doesn’t fit into her class due to that. Her dad, I believe, was a garbage man and who, I think, ended up with her teacher because I remember a part about them going on a date and him saying he ‘even scrubbed behind his ears’ or something along those lines. In some part of the book the girl is at a pier at the ocean and she fall into the ocean (I think) and I remember her saying something about how the salt water stung her eyes. She gets saved by a man who was there and that’s all I remember.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We don't know where or how old you are, so approximately when did you read this book? Was it written in English or another language, and could it have been translated? Any idea which part of the world it was set in? There's a [list of questions in the tag info page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) that might help to jog your memory. Any little detail could help to narrow the search!

Comment: I found [Moonglass](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/8535449), which is about a girl whose mother died (suicide?) and who lives by the ocean (romance with a lifeguard?) but it seems more young-adult than primary-school, so I guess it's not what you're looking for? Ditto [Lily's Crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lily%27s_Crossing). (If either of these is it, I'll post an answer, but I feel like they're probably not.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have updated this post but idk if I should add more. I took a look at the books linked and they don't seem to be the one I was looking for and don't bring up any memories.

Comment: Is the girl's teacher named "Miss Turbone" (not sure of spelling), but people think it's "Mister Bone"?  I read that, but unfortunately I don't remember the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have done some research on the information in the comment above and I have found the book that I was looking for! It is called [Someday Angeline](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/207533.Someday_Angeline) by Louis Sachar, although this is the [cover](https://www.bloomsbury.com/au/someday-angeline-9780747587231/) I'm familiar with. This was the description from [Oldfriendsbookends](https://oldfriendsbookends.blogspot.com/2016/04/someday-angeline-1983-by-louis-sachar.html), via @schweppz's help:

> Angeline has it tough. Her mother died when she was three and she
> lives with her garbage truck driver father (though she loves the
> garbage truck and wants to ride on one). What's worse, she is a
> genius. She remembers things that happened before she was born and at
> eight years old, knows more than her sixth grade teacher. The teacher,
> Mrs. Hardlick, and her classmates resent her intelligence and make fun
> of her for things like sucking her thumb and crying too much.
>
> Angeline meets a boy at recess who is also an outcast at school. His
> name is Gary, though the other kids call him Goon. Gary has a habit of
> making corny jokes, which Angeline always calls the funniest she's
> ever heard (she also laughs too much).
>
> Gary, unlike Angeline, has a good teacher, Miss Turbone, whom he calls
> Mr. Bone (because the names sound the same - I didn't get it at
> first). Miss Turbone invites Gary and Angeline to set up her classroom
> aquariums, and they all get to be friends.

[image: Someday Angeline Bookcover]

Comment: @Leek I think you are probably right but to make it apparent to all who read your answer an appropriate reference might help ( this one looks good coz it includes pertinent plot details ( https://oldfriendsbookends.blogspot.com/2016/04/someday-angeline-1983-by-louis-sachar.html )  although the book's cover is different .

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I tried to improve the answer I provided. If anything is missing, please tell me so I can improve!